# SQLiteStudio can I see the SQLite query generated by clicking options?

Tags: sqlitestudio

I use the wizard in "Tools" (SQLiteStudio 3.2.1, circa June 2019) to import a csv file into a table. I need to repeat the task a few (5) dozen times and I want to submit a query instead of pointing and clicking each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get these SQL statements, but there is something else that may be useful to you.

You can use SQL function available from SQLiteStudio: `import()` as described at https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual#built-in-sql-functions

For example:

```
SELECT import('my_file.txt', 'CSV', 'target_table');
```

This is much easier to repeat.